# Dynamic selector in jQuery

Tags: jquery

my code :

```
<div class="list">
    <ul id="myList1">
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
        <li>d</li>
        <li>e</li>
    </ul>
    <a id="loadMore">Load more</a>
</div>

<div class="list">
    <ul id="myList2" style="display: none;">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
    </ul>
    <a id="loadMore">Load more</a>
</div>
```

`<ul>` id could be mylist2, mylist3, 4, 5 and more.

take a look my work so far :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myList li').hide();

    size_li = $("#myList li").size();
    x=3;
    $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
        $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    });
});
```

it is just to work with static selector. I still can't figure it out how can I put dynamic selector inside jquery script based on `<ul id="mylist1 etc">` and may also on `<a id="loadMore">Load more</a>` to handle click event.

**this is the** [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/43rj8e0c/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` attribute value [should be unique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) in a scope of document, so reason of your problem lies in a fact that you're using `id="loadMore"` instead of e.g. class name `class="loadMore"`.

Your code is also relatively complicated, it can be much simpler if you will use power of jQuery DOM traversal and filtering capabilities:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Taking all UL inside lists
  $('.list > ul').each(function(){
    // Hiding all list elements except first 3
    $(this).find('li').slice(3).hide();
  });
  // Handling clicks to "load more" links
  $('.loadMore').on('click', function() {
    // Searching for previous UL in it
    var $list = $(this).prev('ul');
    // Taking next 5 hidden items and displaying them
    $list.find('li:hidden').slice(0,5).show();
    // If last list item is already visible - hide "load more" link
    if ($list.find('li:last-child').is(':visible')) {
      $list.next('.loadMore').hide();
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.loadMore {
    color:green;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.loadMore:hover {
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
    <ul id="myList">
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
        <li>d</li>
        <li>e</li>
        <li>f</li>
        <li>g</li>
        <li>h</li>
        <li>i</li>
        <li>j</li>
        <li>k</li>
        <li>l</li>
        <li>m</li>
        <li>n</li>
        <li>o</li>
    </ul>
    <a class="loadMore">Load more</a>
</div>

<div class="list">
    <ul id="myList2">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
        <li>11</li>
        <li>12</li>
        <li>13</li>
        <li>14</li>
        <li>15</li>
    </ul>
    <a class="loadMore">Load more</a>
</div>
```

Comment: how can I hide loadmore if there's no more data to load?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to use one button to show 5 more more li items each time you press it.

In that case I would do something like this

```
$('#loadMore').click(function () {    
    var numberOfLisToShow = 5; //for example
    for(var i = 0; i < numberOfLisToShow; i++) {
        //find last visible item and get the next item
        $("ul#yourId li:visible:last").next().show();
    }
});
```

but first try to hide your elements with css not javascript and make sure you leave at least one visible

Comment: Have to admit Flying's answer is better for sure :).